# CSS3 TranslateX relative to current position like jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, translate-animation

I'm creating some kind of slideshow which is setup like so:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide">slide1</div>
    <div class="slide">slide2</div>
    <div class="slide">slide3</div>
</div>
```

To get this working I was using the jQuery animate function to move the (absolute positioned) slides to left or right. This was done by using the relative (-= , +=) properties like so:

```
$('.slide').animate({ left: '+=300' }, 500);
```

But this seems to get really slow on devices like tablets or phones. So, I want to do some performance optimization using CSS3 for this. But...how does one do this?

I tried something like:

```
$('.slide').css({
    'transition' : 'all 1.0s ease-in-out',
    'transform' : 'translateX(-'300px)'
});
```

But that only works once (duh). Nevertheless changing the - to -= does not working either. So the actual question is. How to do the relative stuff jQuery does in CSS3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [step](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) properties of `.animate()`

Just a quick usage example of step:

```
$(element).animate({opacity:1},{
   duration: 500,
   step:function(now, fn){
      fn.start = 0;
      fn.end = 300;
      $(element).css({'left':now});
   }
});
```

`fn.start` - is the starting point and `fn.end` is the end point, for example you want to increment 0 to 300px.

About this code: `transition:all 500ms ease-out 0s;`, you can just leave it on the CSS file. I hope I had given some ideas. Thanks

EDIT: Apply translateX

```
 step:function(now, fn){
            fn.start = 0;
            fn.end = 300;
            $(element).css({
                 '-webkit-transform':'translateX('+now+'%)'
                ,'-moz-transform':'translateX('+now+'%)'
                ,'transform':'translateX('+now+'%)'
            });
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I do not seem to understand where the translateX comes into play?

Comment: I updated my answer, the value of 'now' will depend on what value you assigned to fn.start and fn.end.

Comment: Okay..getting there. But now it seems like it is waiting until the last step and then performs the slide action. I added the transition to the css (on the .slide element) and changed the css defined in the step to: '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(-' + now + 'px)' (this should move to the left).

Comment: can you provide a simple js fiddle? thanks EDIT: also please make sure that the value of transition:all 100ms ease-out 0s; is greater than the delay.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Gamt/    ...   fyi in my case the slideshow is 'neverending', so the first slide is placed on the back when the animation is finished. Of course this is the other way around when sliding the oposite direction.

Comment: I really wanted to help you right now but unfortunately, im on a bus and Im just using my smartphone. I will try to get back on you once I use a pc..

Comment: I understand. No problem. Let me know when you have some new insights.

Comment: you can replace `$(element)` with `$(this)` to make it more generic